# Error: Directory migrations already exists and is not empty from flask db init

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using Postgres DB with Flask migration. I have changed a table name and want to upgrade it to my local & then remote.

Init give:

```
flask db init
Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 4
Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 5
Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 6
Error: Directory migrations already exists and is not empty
```

Migrate gives:

```
(env) (base) Daniyal@Daniyals-MacBook-Pro Website % flask db migrate
Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 4
Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 5
Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 6
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
/Users/Daniyal/Startup/Website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/script/revision.py:152: UserWarning: Revision 6ee19758a13a referenced from 6ee19758a13a -> 2e8e5e007c0a (head), empty message is not present
  util.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Daniyal/Startup/Website/env/bin/flask", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/Daniyal/Startup/Website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 967, in main
    cli.main(args=sys.argv[1:], prog_name="python -m flask" if as_module else None)
  File "/Users/Daniyal/Startup/Website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 586, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Daniyal/Startup/Website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Users/Daniyal/Startup/Website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/Users/Daniyal/Startup/Website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/Users/Daniyal/Startup/Website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/Users/Daniyal/Startup/Website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Daniyal/Startup/Website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Daniyal/Startup/Website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 426, in decorator
    return __ctx.invoke(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Daniyal/Startup/Website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Daniyal/Startup/Website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_migrate/cli.py", line 89, in migrate
    _migrate(directory, message, sql, head, splice, branch_label, version_path,
  File "/Users/Daniyal/Startup/Website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_migrate/__init__.py", line 96, in wrapped
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Daniyal/Startup/Website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_migrate/__init__.py", line 210, in migrate
    command.revision(config, message, autogenerate=True, sql=sql,
  File "/Users/Daniyal/Startup/Website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 214, in revision
    script_directory.run_env()
  File "/Users/Daniyal/Startup/Website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 489, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
  File "/Users/Daniyal/Startup/Website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 98, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "/Users/Daniyal/Startup/Website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/util/compat.py", line 184, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "migrations/env.py", line 96, in <module>
    run_migrations_online()
  File "migrations/env.py", line 90, in run_migrations_online
    context.run_migrations()
  File "<string>", line 8, in run_migrations
  File "/Users/Daniyal/Startup/Website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/runtime/environment.py", line 846, in run_migrations
    self.get_context().run_migrations(**kw)
  File "/Users/Daniyal/Startup/Website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/runtime/migration.py", line 511, in run_migrations
    for step in self._migrations_fn(heads, self):
  File "/Users/Daniyal/Startup/Website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 190, in retrieve_migrations
    revision_context.run_autogenerate(rev, context)
  File "/Users/Daniyal/Startup/Website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/autogenerate/api.py", line 442, in run_autogenerate
    self._run_environment(rev, migration_context, True)
  File "/Users/Daniyal/Startup/Website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/autogenerate/api.py", line 454, in _run_environment
    self.script_directory.get_revisions("heads")
  File "/Users/Daniyal/Startup/Website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 227, in get_revisions
    return self.revision_map.get_revisions(id_)
  File "/Users/Daniyal/Startup/Website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/script/revision.py", line 321, in get_revisions
    resolved_id, branch_label = self._resolve_revision_number(id_)
  File "/Users/Daniyal/Startup/Website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/script/revision.py", line 501, in _resolve_revision_number
    self._revision_map
  File "/Users/Daniyal/Startup/Website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/util/langhelpers.py", line 230, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File "/Users/Daniyal/Startup/Website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/script/revision.py", line 156, in _revision_map
    down_revision = map_[downrev]
KeyError: '6ee19758a13a'
```

I am not sure why upgrading such a trivial change to DB's schema has to be such a hassle.

I would really appreciate your help on how I can make such change.

Comment: please add full stacktrace

Comment: Really sorry, I tried doing so and got "too much code" error & didn't know what else to write. I'll retry

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798937/cant-migrate-or-upgrade-database-with-flask-migrate-alembic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't migrate or upgrade database with Flask-Migrate (Alembic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798937/cant-migrate-or-upgrade-database-with-flask-migrate-alembic)

Comment: yeah I ended up dropping it since it was in development. Thanks guys!